# How to turn ternary if statement back into standard javascript?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm working with this ternary if statement:

```
a[textProp] = _newText + ' (' + (_newText === a[textProp] ? 'no change' : 'changed') + ')';
```

And I'd like to turn it back into standard javascript (for the sake of readability). I additionally want to make it into an if, else if, else statement to test if the variable is empty/null.

This is what I have, which doesn't work:

```
if (_newText = null) {
'Invalid Record';
}
else if (_newText === a[textProp]) {
'no change';
}
else(_newText != a[textProp]) {
'changed';
}
+ ')';
```

Comment: You don't get an error by using a test in the `else` statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (_newText = null) {
             ^
```

needs to be

```
if (_newText == null) {
             ^^
```

or

```
if (_newText === null) {
             ^^^
```

And you need to build up your string

```
a[textProp] = 'Invalid Record';
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of readability, I'd start with something like this, where each state is checked explicitly (valid and changed):

```
var isValid = true;
if (_newText == null || _newText.trim().length === 0) {
  isValid = false;
}

var hasChanged = false;
if (isValid && _newText !== a[textProp]) {
  hasChanged = true;
}

if (!isValid) {
  a[textProp] = 'Invalid Record';
}
else if (hasChanged) {
  a[textProp] = _newText + ' (changed)';
}
else {
  a[textProp] += ' (no change)';
}
```

But, I also think it's not right to store the result of the tests as a string inside `a[textProp]`, it could invalidate future tests. I'd probably have separate keys for the test results (as a flag), e.g.: `a.valid[textProp]` and `a.changed[textProp]` (in this case, `textProp` can never be `"valid"` or `"changed"`). Even better would be to store the text in `a[textProp].text`, and the flags in `a[textProp].valid` and `a[textProp].changed`.

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting the invalid record to work. Check out my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pfeff/WnaBD/1/

Comment: Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/WnaBD/2/). Note that what I mentioned happens if you click the button multiple times.

Comment: I did notice that before, but check out the 9th list item. It has no record number, so I want something like 'invalid' to be appended to it instead of no change. Any ideas?